# How to implement automatic app update like facebook?

Tags: android

Since I have downloaded facebook in my phone **it always updates automatically**. I don't need to go to `playstore` and update it.

How can I implement this **great feature** in my android app.

Comment: **It's the feature of playstore not Facebook..!!**

Comment: will you please share some link or info about this feature

Comment: automatic app update feature is not part of facebook app. you can check in play store application settings. If you want to notify your app user to update available in case automatic update check is disabled in play store application use push notification

Comment: auto-update feature is on in my playstore but still I need to go to playstore and update the app I created while facebook says .. downloding updates automatically

Answer (score 1):

**There is no feature like this you can implement in Your App.**

Your Facebook app is updated automatically because there is a setting in your playstore for **Auto Updating** Apps.

With this reference of [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=en-IN) :

1. Open the Google Play Store app.
2. Tap Menu and then Settings.
3. Tap Auto-update apps.
4. Select an option:

   - Auto update apps at any time: Updates apps at any time, using either Wi-Fi or mobile data.
   - Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi only: Updates only when you are connected to Wi-Fi.

See this link for more details.